# sum of numbers works in data frame, but not in tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, tibble

I wanted to add up all numbers in a column of a tibble as an exercise to learn R, and used the example data set `forcats::gss_cat`. I wanted to look at the marital status by age:

```
by_ag <- gss_cat %>%
filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
group_by(age, marital) %>%
count() 
by_age <- by_ag %>%
mutate(prop = n/sum(n))

ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = marital)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

and this is what I get:
[image: plot from tibble]

Obviously, the calculated proportion is not really a proportion, as `sum(n)` is actually equal to `n`. To help identify the problem, I created a small data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("new", "old", "don't know"), number = c(20, 12, 34))
```

and calculated a proportion as well:

```
df %>%
  mutate(prop = number/sum(number))
```

This works as expected:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
type       number  prop
<chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 new          20.0 0.303
2 old          12.0 0.182
3 don't know   34.0 0.515
```

I thus converted my initial tibble to a data frame and reran the code:

```
by_age <- as.data.frame(by_ag) %>%
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = marital)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

and got a perfect plot:
[image: plot from data frame]

Thus, my initial conclusion was that the reason was I originally had a tibble. Thus, to check this assumption I also created a new tibble:

```
df <- tibble(type = c("new", "old", "don't know"), number = c(20, 12, 34))
df %>%
  mutate(prop = number/sum(number))
```

and then got completely confused as here, calculating the proportion worked without problems:

```
A tibble: 3 x 3
type       number  prop
<chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 new          20.0 0.303
2 old          12.0 0.182
3 don't know   34.0 0.515
```

So why does `sum(n)` not work in my initial example?

I would like to add that this comes from an exercise from R for Data Science ([working with factors](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html)) and they do not ungroup:
[image]
So what might be the reason for that?

Comment: You may need `ungroup` because the `by_ag` is a grouped object

Comment: This actually works. But can you explain why this step is necessary? I would have assumed that the calculations produce a tibble with a new column named "n", and taking the sum of these values should not depend on grouping?

Comment: Because you are still doing the `sum` within each group instead of the whole column 'n'.  Check with your example `df` i.e. `df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(Sum = sum(number))`

Comment: This actually is an exercise from [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html), and they did not ungroup to create their plot. Any idea why they did not need to do this?

Comment: I think in the link they are using `summarise`, right?.  After the summarise step one of the group gets stripped off.  In your case, tehre are two groups, so, even if one group is gone, there is still a group that is left which caused the trouble

Comment: I updated the question with what they did - there is no summarize in that code.

Comment: I see `group_by(age, marital)` in the code..  The key difference is shown in the solution posted below

Comment: I think what you are trying to convey is that by converting to `as.data.frame`, it works.  It is because now the grouping is lost because you are stripping of all those classes, just like with `ungroup`

Comment: I think I was able to follow your responses. What I still do not understand is why it seemed to work without ungrouping in the online example. The `relig_summary` has nothing to do with the tibble I was working on (see above). The authors also added two grouping variables, and the code seemed to run without problems.

Comment: May be it is a different version.

Comment: In the version that I have `dplyr_0.7.4`, the prop is all 1s by following their code.  Are you saying that you should get the exact output even if the versions are not the same?

Comment: maybe it is my limited knowledge of R, but when I copy and paste the code from the online example, I do not get their plot, but the one with the straight line. I have problems to follow why a summarise function that was used before should influence this section?

Comment: Ok, I think I explained the reasons in the solution below.  If There is documentation as to why `summarise` behaves after group by in such a way

Comment: I do very much appreciate, and will try to learn more to completely understand.

Comment: I would suggest not to fully follow the document completely as function behavior changes with new version.  Always check the `str` as to we something is not behavign as expected

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: It is also possible that when somebody writes a document that he may copy a code which may be a prior version that is not working correctly.  Anyway, one take away from this whole exercise,is that you learned the behavior of those functions which you will not forget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the 'by_ag' is a grouped object, therefore, the `sum` of 'n' is doing the sum within each 'group'.  The option would be to extract the column i.e. `.$n`

```
by_ag %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(.$n))
```

or `ungroup` the object and then do the `sum`

```
by_ag %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```

---

To illustrate the difference, using the OP's 'df'

```
df %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
    mutate(Sum = sum(number))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups: type [3]
#  type       number   Sum
#  <fctr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 new          20.0  20.0
#2 old          12.0  12.0
#3 don't know   34.0  34.0

df %>% 
    group_by(type) %>%
    mutate(Sum = sum(.$number))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups: type [3]
#  type       number   Sum
#  <fctr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 new          20.0  66.0
#2 old          12.0  66.0
#3 don't know   34.0  66.0
```

---

Based on the comments from the OP, the exercise [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html) used a single grouping variable which gets stripped off after the `summarise`

```
relig_summary <- gss_cat %>%
   group_by(relig) %>%
   summarise(
     age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE),
     tvhours = mean(tvhours, na.rm = TRUE),
     n = n()
   )

str(relig_summary)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       15 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ relig  : Factor w/ 16 levels "No answer","Don't know",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ age    : num  49.5 35.9 40 38.9 40.1 ...
# $ tvhours: num  2.72 4.62 2.87 3.46 2.79 ...
# $ n      : int  93 15 109 23 689 95 104 32 71 147 ...
```

Instead of one grouping variable, we add two,

```
by_ag <- gss_cat %>%
            filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
            group_by(age, marital) %>%
            count()    

str(by_ag) #check the grouped_df class
#Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 351 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ age    : int  18 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 ...
# $ marital: Factor w/ 6 levels "No answer","Never married",..: 2 6 2 4 5 6 2 3 4 6 ...
# $ n      : int  89 2 234 3 1 11 227 1 2 21 ...
# - attr(*, "vars")= chr  "age" "marital"
# - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "indices")=List of 351
```

When we convert to a `data.frame`, the grouping attributes are lost

```
as.data.frame(by_ag) %>% 
           str
#'data.frame':   351 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ age    : int  18 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 ...
#$ marital: Factor w/ 6 levels "No answer","Never married",..: 2 6 2 4 5 6 2 3 4 6 ...
#$ n      : int  89 2 234 3 1 11 227 1 2 21 ...
```

Similar to `ungroup`

```
by_ag %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     str
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       351 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ age    : int  18 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 ...
# $ marital: Factor w/ 6 levels "No answer","Never married",..: 2 6 2 4 5 6 2 3 4 6 ...
# $ n      : int  89 2 234 3 1 11 227 1 2 21 ...
```